# How to get previous and next words for current selection in FabricJS?

Tags: fabricjs

I'm wondering how to find a previous and next words in Textbox element of FabricJS.
Assume I have the next text:

> Hello beautiful world.

Currently, my cursor stands on "**beautiful**", so I want to get "**Hello**" as a text before and "**world**" as a text after.

Any ideas?
Tnx

http://jsfiddle.net/redlive/gdyvfj1h/1/

```js
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

function getBeforeAndAfter(text){
 const start = text.selectionStart;
 const end = text.selectionEnd;
 const textBefore = '';
 const textAfter = '';
 ///////////// THIS LOGIC NEEDS TO BE DEVELOPED HERE /////
 $('#before').val( textBefore );
 $('#after').val( textAfter );
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('paper');
canvas.setHeight(300);
canvas.setWidth(500);

var text = new fabric.Textbox('Hello beautiful world', {
  left: 50,
  top: 10,
  fontFamily: 'arial',
  fill: '#333',
  fontSize: 50
});
text.selectionStart = 6;
text.selectionEnd = 15;
canvas.add(text);
canvas.renderAll();


$("#btn").on("click", function(t){
 getBeforeAndAfter(text);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.19/fabric.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="paper" width="400" height="400" style="border:1px solid #ccc"></canvas>
Text before:
<input type="text" id="before" disabled/>
<br>
Text after:
<input type="text" id="after" disabled/>
<br>
<button id="btn">Get Before and After</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function getBeforeAndAfter(text){
    const start = text.selectionStart;
    const end = text.selectionEnd;

    text.selectionStart = text.findWordBoundaryLeft( start - 1 );
    text.selectionEnd = start;
    const textBefore = text.getSelectedText();

    text.selectionStart = end;
    text.selectionEnd = text.findWordBoundaryRight( end + 1 );
    const textAfter = text.getSelectedText();

    $('#before').val( textBefore );
    $('#after').val( textAfter );
}
```

Working version is here 
http://jsfiddle.net/redlive/gdyvfj1h/6/

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `getBeforeAndAfter` function, do this:

#### Logic

First, set the currently selected word to `currentWord` from the string by calling `.slice` on  the Textbox's `.text` property. Provide `start` and `end` as your arguments. You now have the selected word ('beautiful').

Second, `split` the string by a single space.

Third, find the `indexOf` your selected word (1).

Finally, your previous word's content is `words[currentWordIndex - 1]` and your next word's content is `words[currentWordIndex + 1]`.

#### Example:

```
function getBeforeAndAfter(text){
    const string = text.text;
    const start = text.selectionStart;
    const end = text.selectionEnd;
    const currentWord = string.slice(start, end);
    
    const words = string.split(" ");
    const index = words.indexOf(currentWord);

    const textBefore = words[index-1];
    const textAfter = words[index+1];

    $('#before').val( textBefore );
    $('#after').val( textAfter );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your code, but it's better to use findWordBoundaryLeft and findWordBoundaryRight functions.